# Github actions merge specific pull request

Tags: git, github, github-actions

What i need is to merge a pull request opened previously by the same Github Action, but i need to merge only that specific pull request as for example if x is editing file y in feature 1 and open a pull request i don't want that one to be merged. If the Github actions create a pull request as in the example below i need it to merge only the one created by itself or by specific pull request name.

Are there any solutions to this?

```
merge-branch:
    if: ${{ github.event.label.name == 'commit' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: test1
        uses: devmasx/merge-branch@v1.3.1
        with:
          type: now
          from_branch: feature1
          target_branch: master
          github_token: ${{ github.token }}
```

Comment: You could use an `auto-approve `action (https://github.com/hmarr/auto-approve-action) that would only approve pull request from the `github-actions [bot]`, and then an `auto-merge` action (https://github.com/pascalgn/automerge-action) to merge only pull request with a specific label or when they are approved. Would it be an option here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately the bot would create multiple pull requests and we still want to approve specific ones by name not by user.

Comment: You could also use the `if` conditional to check if the title or the prefix contains or is equal to a specific field through `github.event.pull_request.title`, then execute the operation you want.

Comment: Great answer, than you! @GuiFalourd

Comment: I'll add it as official answer then, so it could help other as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to approve specific PRs by username:**

You could use an [auto-approve action](http://github.com/hmarr/auto-approve-action) that would only approve pull request from the `github-actions [bot]`, and then an [auto-merge action](http://github.com/pascalgn/automerge-action) to merge only pull request with a specific label or when they are approved.

**If you want to approve specific PRs by name:**

You could use the `if` [conditional](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) in your workflow to check if the title or the prefix contains or is equal to a specific field through `github.event.pull_request.title`. There is also this action ([check-pull-request-title](https://github.com/DylanVann/check-pull-request-title)) that might help to perform the same operation.